# Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION returns 0 for work profile apps in Pixel

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, rotation, intune

I am working on an enterprise mobile app targeted for Android 13. This app is distributed and configured through MS Intune on our customers' devices. We have observed that for Pixel devices running Android 13, the following line of code within the app:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(applicationContext.getContentResolver(),
Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0)
```

always returns 0 within the work profile. However, the same app functions correctly when installed in the standard manner (without work profile ). Consequently, we are unable to detect whether 'Auto Rotate' has been turned on or off in the device settings while the app is installed in the work profile.

It's worth noting that this code works as expected on one of the Samsung devices we have tested (Galaxy S22 Plus running Android 13).

Are we overlooking something, or is this a known issue? Your prompt attention to this matter would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, both devices have Company Portal app version 5.0.5998.0 installed.

I tried other ways to detect if the Auto rotate settings is turn on or off but unfortunately we did not find any.

Comment: Another tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301825120